# How does iperf calculate throughput and jitter?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, iperf

I've read that Iperf basically tries to send as much information down a connection as quickly as possible reporting on the throughput achieved. This tool is especially useful in determining the volume of data that links between two machines can supply.

Is it possible to gather the same results by sending regular data, as in not testing data?

What I'm trying to do is sending data in the foreground while gathering statistics in the background (throughput and jitter).

How iperf calculates these two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest thing I've found

http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar question about how iperf works. Please refer to the following post where I did some research and gave an overview.

[How iperf calculates network statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063074/how-iperf-calculates-network-statistics)

Generally, in iperf, it embedded timestamps and sequence number in the payload in the sender side. When receiver receives the packet, it extracts these content and calculates the statistics. You can find more detail in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Throughput is simple: assuming the client is saturating the network, the server only needs to count the received bytes, and divide that by some duration.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193916/proper-way-to-calculate-link-throughput) explains this topic in a greater detail.

Iperf 2 calculates Jitter for UDP only. It is based on what is prescribed within by RTP implementation, as stated by [the code](https://sourceforge.net/p/iperf2/code/ci/55c81250094915b1c4fe8714db6ed5861b6b7fe3/tree/src/Reporter.c#l1147).

RTP is used in implementations of audio streaming, where jitter plays a major role, so it's a good place to take the algorithm from - what Iperf reports is what many applications where you would be interested in jitter would see.

See [RFC 1889, section 6.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1889#section-6.3.1), "interarrival jitter" field:

> The interarrival jitter J is defined to be the mean deviation (smoothed
> absolute value) of the difference D in packet spacing at the receiver compared
> to the sender for a pair of packets. As shown in the equation below, this is
> equivalent to the difference in the "relative transit time" for the two
> packets; the relative transit time is the difference between a packet's RTP
> timestamp and the receiver's clock at the time of arrival, measured in the same
> units.
>
> If Si is the RTP timestamp from packet i, and Ri is the time of arrival in RTP
> timestamp units for packet i, then for two packets i and j, D may be expressed
> as
>
> ```
>  D(i,j)=(Rj-Ri)-(Sj-Si)=(Rj-Sj)-(Ri-Si)
> ```
>
> The interarrival jitter is calculated continuously as each data packet i is
> received from source SSRC_n, using this difference D for that packet and the
> previous packet i-1 in order of arrival (not necessarily in sequence),
> according to the formula
>
> ```
> J=J+(|D(i-1,i)|-J)/16
> ```